# How to add Arabic using report as document class?

Tags: arabic, report

I am using this template,
and I want to add an abstract in arabic. The abstract in arabic is included separately in the destination: ./chapitres/resume/resume_Ar; as it is clearly shown from the code:

```
%% 
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\huge}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{20pt}{20pt}[0pt]
\usepackage{acronym}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{14}{16}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{13}{13}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{12}}
 
%\titleformat{\chapter}%[display]
%{\normalfont\chapfnt\scshape}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}





\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} {0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
%\usepackage{xspace}

%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.12,0.47,0.87}


%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % alignement image

%\synctex=1
%%%%%%%%% interligne 1.5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bidi=default,french]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% bibliographie par chapitre :
%     * mettre \bibliography et \bibliographystyle dans chaque fichier inclu
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
%ajouté

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%[left=3.2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
% permet de faire une table des matières par chapitre
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{color}
% ajoute (entre autre) la bibliographie dans la table des matières
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array, diagbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}

%\cleardoublepage

%\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
%\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
%\usepackage{ntheorem}
%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{lem}{Lemme}[section]
%\newtheorem{cory}{Corollaire}[section]
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Définition}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{verbatim}


%\usepackage{multirow}

% style de numérotation
\usepackage{engrec}
%\usepackage{a4++}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\thepart{\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@table}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@equation}



\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}
%profondeur de numérotation
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}%pour la numérotation dans le corps du document
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%fancy
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{}

%Ajouter des entete au chapitre non numeroté
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1]{\chapter*{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    \markboth{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
%\markboth{\slshape{#1}}{\slshape{#1}}}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textbf{\chaptername\ 
                %   \thechapter. #1}{}}}

\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %Conny

\ChTitleUpperCase \ChTitleAsIs \ChNameAsIs
%\ChNameLowerCase \ChTitleLowerCase \ChNameVar{\centering\Huge\rm\bfseries}
\ChNumVar{\Huge} \ChRuleWidth{2pt} \ChTitleVar{\centering\Huge}




%lien hypertex
\usepackage{hyperref} % Créer des liens et des signets
\hypersetup{    
    colorlinks=false, %colorise les liens
    breaklinks=true, %permet le retour à la ligne dans les liens trop longs
    urlcolor= blue, %couleur des hyperliens
    linkcolor= blue,    %couleur des liens internes
    citecolor=blue, %couleur des références
    %pdftitle={Rapport de stage}, %informations apparaissant dans
    %pdfauthor={Anonyme}, %les informations du document
    %pdfsubject={Simulation}    %sous Acrobat.
}
% biblio ordonnee classique
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


%\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemme}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothèse}[chapter]

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{natbib}  % 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}




%**********************************************************
%\newcommand\chapterstring{Chapitre}
%
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%
%% chapitres
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\bfseries\sffamily\color{Blue4}} {\filright
%   \enspace \Large \chapterstring~\thechapter} {14pt} {\Huge\filcenter}
%
%% sections
%\titleformat{\section}{\vspace{0mm plus 2cm}\addpenalty{-1000}\color{Blue4}\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{1em}{}
%[{\color{Blue4}\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
%
%% sous-sections
%\titleformat{\subsection}{\addpenalty{-500}\large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} 
%
%% sous-sous-sections
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\penalty-500\vspace{0pt plus 2pt}{}\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesubsubsection}{}{}[\vspace{-14pt}]

%******************************
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{\textsc{Tableau}}}

% METTRE EQUATIONS EN GRAS
%\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{\begingroup\bfseries\mathversion{bold}#1\endgroup}
\raggedbottom
%\flushbottom


\begin{document}
        \dominitoc
    
        
            %%%%%% Résumé en arabe
        \begingroup
        \def\MakeUppercase#1{#1}
        \include{./chapitres/resume/resume_Ar}
        \endgroup
        
        % table des matières generale
        \begin{spacing}{0.5}
        \begingroup
        \def\MakeUppercase#1{#1}
        \tableofcontents
        \vspace{-100pt}
        \endgroup
        \end{spacing}
        
        
    \end{document}
```

And the code for the abstract in arabic using your code in mine:

```
\chaptertoc{Résumé en Arabe}
 \vspace{-90pt}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Resumé}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
ملخص الكتاب

\end{otherlanguage}
```

When generating the code I get no errors, however nothing is shown in the Arabic abstract as shown in the screenshot included:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of a report with an abstract in Arabic:

```
% to compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bidi=default,french]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


 \begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}

\begin{abstract}

علم الفلك هو علم طبيعي يدرس الظواهر الفلكية والأجرام السماوية. 
%
يستخدم علم الفلك الرياضيات والفيزياء والكيمياء لشرح أصل وتطور تلك الظواهر والأجرام. 
تشمل الأجرام المثيرة للاهتمام الكواكب والأقمار والنجوم والسدم والمجرات والمذنبات. وتشمل الظواهر ذات الصلة انفجارات المستعر الأعظم، انفجارات أشعة جاما، والنجوم الزائفة، والنجوم الزائفة المتوهجة، والنجوم الناب
ضة، وإشعاع الخلفية الكونية الميكروي. بشكل عام، يدرس علم الفلك كل ما ينشأ خارج الغلاف الجوي للأرض. 
علم الكون هو فرع من فروع علم الفلك. يدرس الفضاء الكوني ككل

\end{abstract}

\end{otherlanguage}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hafid Boukhoulda, when trying** your code** separately it worked just fine, but when including the part of your code in mine it did not work and no Arabic text was shown unfortunately.   I tried to include                                                                              `` \usepackage[bidi=default,french]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}`` and the part with the text in Arabic but it did not work.

Comment: @user13091672 update your question with  a so called "Minimal working example" e.g. an example that include only the necessary packages and latex code that shows the problem.

Comment: @user13091672 I’m not sure in what way it didn’t work, but if you’re using legacy fonts in your original document, these commands will load ``fontspec` and override them.

Comment: Thank you again @Hafid Boukhoulda, I updated my question this time using your code in mine, and nothing showed in Arabic as always.

Comment: @user13091672 thank you for your comment, I couldn't understand what did you mean by legacy fonts, if you could be just more clear about what should I exactly add or do to my code, I will be thankful

Comment: @user13091672 I suspect you might have meant to reply to me, rather than to yourself. What I meant is, you seem to be trying to load both a modern Unicode font with `fontspec` and an 8-bit encoding from last century, with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Normally, you would do only one or the other (although you can if you really do need to).

Comment: @user13091672 The template also seems to have been written by copying and pasting from the preambles of multiple documents, and contains many duplicate or redundant packages.

Comment: @Davislor yes indeed I was trying replying you I am sorry  for that. And thank you it worked when deleting the \ usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Thank you again for your remarks and assistance.